# How to backup NodeMCU firmware?

Tags: backup, firmware, nodemcu

How do I backup my NodeMCU firmware before upgrading?

Note: I am a completely newbie at this. I have never worked with a NodeMCU before. I have other programming skills, so programming is not new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esptool.py` has a (undocumented) [`read_flash` option](https://github.com/espressif/esptool/blob/master/esptool.py#L1748) which you can use to read the firmware from 0x0000 back to a local file.

```
$ esptool.py read_flash
usage: esptool read_flash [-h] [--no-progress] address size filename
esptool read_flash: error: too few arguments
```